# Call R function from C# console application

Tags: c#, r, function, console-application

I have a **R function** deployed on R server and It accepts 2 parameters. I have IpAddress and Port of R server. How I can call this method for a C# console application. If there any workings sample available where we first connect with R server using **IPAddress and port** and then call the R function.
I have googled but the results which I found does not serve my purpose. So If any body has any sample working code, i will appreciate that.

Comment: *"R function deployed on R server"* is a little vague. What "R server" are you using? `Rserve`? `opencpu`? `plumber`?

Comment: @r2evans , sorry for the confusion. 
Rserve is being used. code is on some linux server which i am able to access using terminus, but I have to call that function from c#.

Comment: Have you checked out the Rserve [doc page](http://www.rforge.net/Rserve/doc.html)? It shows a C# client as http://sourceforge.net/projects/rservelink/.

Comment: @r2evans I had checked that but that was updated in 2007, so I was wondering if some new library is available.
Currently when I checked using this library this gives some timeout error.

Comment: I thought it was only 5-6 years ago, not 13 years, but your point is valid. I don't have experience with `Rserve`, only with tools like `plumber` and `opencpu` (more recently in the former, not the latter). Both of them completely insulate the caller (your C#) from having to know anything, it's simply an HTTP end point that accepts headers, form-data, etc. Sorry I can't advise on Rserve.